# Mordell's theorem-Finitely generated abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, finitely-generated

In my lecture notes we have the following:

Mordell proved the following:

Let $C$ be a nonsingular cubic curve with rational coefficients. Then the abelian group of rational points on $C$ is finitely generated.

$$E|_{\mathbb{Q}} \ \ \ \ y^2=x^3+ax+b$$ $ \left( a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \ \ , \ \ \ D(f) \neq 0 \right )$

$$E(\mathbb{Q})=\{(\alpha , \beta ) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} | \beta^2=\alpha^3+a \alpha +b \} \cup \{ \left [0, 1, 0\right ]\}$$

That means that $$E(\mathbb{Q})=E(\mathbb{Q})_t \times \mathbb{Z}^r, r \geq 0$$

$$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}=\{P \in E(\mathbb{Q}) | P \text{ of finite order }\}$$

$\mathbb{Z}^r$ is the direct product of cyclic groups of finite order.

$$$$

---

$$$$

Can you explain why $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is the union of $\{(\alpha , \beta ) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} | \beta^2=\alpha^3+a \alpha +b \} $ and $\{ \left [0, 1, 0\right ]\}$ ???

The group contains the rational points of a non-Singular cubic curve, so it contains the set $\{(\alpha , \beta ) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} | \beta^2=\alpha^3+a \alpha +b \} $ . But why does it also contain the set $\{ \left [0, 1, 0\right ]\}$ ???

$$$$

How do we conclude to $E(\mathbb{Q})=E(\mathbb{Q})_t \times \mathbb{Z}^r, r \geq 0$ ??? What does this mean ???

Answer (score 1):

There are two somewhat unrelated questions:

- The "exceptional" point ought to be the "point at infinity" (though you do not give enough details to be certain); to have a nice group-law on the curve you need to consider it in projective space not just the affine part.
- $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is a commutative group. For any commutative group $G$ one can consider  $G_t$ the subset of elements of finite order. This forms a subgroup called the torsion subgroup of $G$. Every **finitely generated** commutative group is of the form $G_t \oplus \mathbb{Z}^r$ where $G_t$ is the torsion subgroup, an in this case finite commutative group. (This is a result from group theory and does not really depend on the specific of this situation.)

Comment: Do we include $[0, 1, 0 ]$ at $$E(\mathbb{Q})=\{(\alpha , \beta ) \in \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} | \beta^2=\alpha^3+a \alpha +b \} \cup \{ \left [0, 1, 0\right ]\}$$ to show that $b$ is at the same equivalence class as $1$ ??? 

$$$$ 

At $$G_t \oplus \mathbb{Z}^r$$ what is $r$ ???

Comment: You include the point at infinity since you consider all the points in projective space, this means you consider all solutions of $zy^2= x^3 + axz^2 + bz^3$ and then introcuduce the usual equivalence relation. The equivalence class of the solution $(0,1,0)$ consists of all $(0,q,0)$ for $q$ a rational. For the second question: the $r$ is some nonnegative integer; you have $r$ copies of the integers; it is like you consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ for exmample for $3$-dimensional space. Here you have $r$ dimension and only integers, like a grid. The $r$ is called the rank of the curve.

Comment: why do we have only the $y-$coordinate non-zero? why are the points at the projective space of the form $[0,1,0]$ ? and not for example $[1,0,0]$ ?

Comment: If $z=0$ then to get a solution of the equation I gave we also most have $x=0$. So the only solutions for $z=0$ are $(0,q,0)$ forming a single class. For solutions with $z\neq 1$ we choose the representive with $z=1$ and this reduces the equation I gave to finding the $(\alpha,\beta)$.